# How to edit the text coming together with the numeration of pages in pdf produced out of a notebook?

Tags: notebooks, formatting

I am writing a text that I am going to publish on-line. When I transform it from the notebook into the pdf format I get the numeration style typical for Mathematica:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I would like to edit the text following the page numeration. For example, instead of "2|Supporting Materials 3.nb" I would like to leave either simple "2" or "2|Supporting materials".
My question is: is it possible to edit this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that in the [“Headers and footers” dialog](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/HeadersAndFooters.html):

[image]

or [right in the notebook with `PageHeaders`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PageHeaders.html).